# React Native 0.26: iOS and Android version support

Tags: react-native

Which versions of iOS and Android does React Native 0.26 support?

I can't find this in the React Native main site or GitHub pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Supported operating systems are >= Android 4.1 (API 16) and >= iOS
>   7.0.

You should've looked harder! It's on there github page:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native

Comment: Any idea why I need latest version of xCode to build React Native for iOS 7.0? I have xCode 6.2 which supports iOS 8.2. But can't use React Native unless upgrade to xCode 7, which means I have to upgrade OS X to El Capitan which will kill other software I use.

Comment: .@GiantElk I'm pretty sure that's what they say you need, but in reality older versions of xcode should work. Don't quote me on that though. I haven't updated my xcode in ages, so I must have a n older version

Comment: Well it doesn't work > in reality older versions of xcode should work. I get it that there may be other reasons for RN to require latest xCode beside iOS version support. Wish they'd document that in Release Notes.

Comment: documentation tells you need  android api 23. Look weird to me.

Comment: No it doesn't, If you click the link and read it, it says the supported operating systems android 4.1 AND greater + IOS 7.0 AND GREATER @heat